# JS - getting the longest non-repeating character substring from a string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to solve a task on the [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-substring-without-repeating-characters/description/) site. My approach to solving this problem was to iterate over a string, and then fill first one array until I find a repeating character, and then start filling another array, until I find a repeating character there as well. Once I would have two filled arrays, I would compare them and keep the longer one, until I am done with iteration. But with these approach I end up checking a lot of things and not sure what to do when I have the `secondArray` filled and I am still doing the subiteration, to avoid filling the `firstArray` as well.
In general this code is to cumbersome, and I am not sure anymore how should I solve this?

```
s = "anviaj"
s = "eeydgwdykpv"

var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
    let firstArray = [];
    let secondArray = [];
    let firstArrayFull = false;
    let secondArrayFull = false;
    let subIterationFinished = false;
    if (s.length == 1)
            return s;
    for (var i = 0; i < s.length -1; i++) {
        if (!firstArrayFull) {
            firstArray.push(s.charAt(i));
        } else if (!secondArrayFull) { secondArray.push(s.charAt(i)); } 
        for (let j = i + 1; j < s.length; j++) {
            if (j + 1 == s.length) { 
                subIterationFinished = true;
                checkArrays();
            }  
            if (!firstArrayFull && !firstArray.includes(s.charAt(j))) {
                if (secondArrayFull && !subIterationFinished) {
                   firstArray = firstArray;
                } else {
                   firstArray.push(s.charAt(j));
                }

            } else { 
                firstArrayFull = true;
                if (secondArrayFull) {
                    checkArrays();
                }
            } 
            if (firstArrayFull && secondArray.length != 0 && secondArray.includes(s.charAt(j))) { 
                secondArrayFull = true;
                checkArrays();
             }
            if (firstArrayFull && secondArray.length != 0 && !secondArray.includes(s.charAt(j))) {
                secondArray.push(s.charAt(j));
            }
        }
    }

    function checkArrays() {
        if (secondArray.length > firstArray.length) {
            firstArray = [];
            firstArrayFull = false;
            secondArrayFull = true;
        } else {
            secondArray = [];
            secondArrayFull = false;
            firstArrayFull = true;
        }
    }

    return secondArray.length > firstArray.length ? secondArray : firstArray;
};

console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring(s));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use two variable, one to keep track of the longest substring and the other to keep track of current longest substring without repetition. 
Iterate through your string.
Check if the current word contains the current character.

If it contains, then checks the length of current word with the longest substring. If it is greater, the update the longest substring.

Update the current word from the last seen index till the length of the current word.

Continue till end of your input string.

```js
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
    var longestSubstring = '';
    var currentWord = '';
    for(var i = 0 ; i < s.length ; i++){
      var foundIndex = currentWord.indexOf(s[i]);
      if(foundIndex > -1){
        if(longestSubstring.length < currentWord.length)
          longestSubstring = currentWord;
        currentWord = currentWord.slice(foundIndex+1);
      }
      currentWord += s[i];
    }
  return longestSubstring.length < currentWord.length ? currentWord.length : longestSubstring.length;
};

console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("bbbbb"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcdaajkljl"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("pwwkew"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("ysbghjjrfumqjpyktddsnxftvdqgxzlvrneaynufhgyqxwaqzelmbsiyxaubrqvguvehpmrykhvikkqzwttg"));
```

Comment: Isn't this a O(n^2) solution?

Comment: @lilezek It is nearly 0(n) solution, the reason being using `indexof()` is restricted to length of 27 characters of lower case alphabets. So, we are nearly just scanning through the string of input. One optimization, I could see is instead of storing substring one could have a dictionary look up.

Comment: for lower case alphabets yes, but for a valid character as a key in object, the complexity grows to O(n * validNumberOfCharactersAllowed)

Answer (score 1):

This is a **valid**, **O(n)** solution which only constructs the final string once, tested against a 20.000 length string (it should be still fast with a million characters, but stackoverflow limits input to 30K characters).

```js
/**
 * @param {string} s
 * @return {number}
 */
var lengthOfLongestSubstring = function(s) {
    var l = 0;
    var r = 0;
    var maxL = 0;
    var maxR = 0;
    var length = () => r - l;
    var maxLength = () => maxR - maxL;
    var keys = {};
    while (r < s.length) {
        if (s[r] in keys) {
            var newL = keys[s[r]] + 1;
            for (var i = l; i < newL; i++) {
                delete keys[s[i]];
            }
            if (maxLength() < length()) {
                maxL = l;
                maxR = r;
            }
            l = newL;
        }
        keys[s[r]] = r;
        r = r + 1;
    }

    if (maxLength() < length()) {
        maxL = l;
        maxR = r;
    }
    
    return maxLength();
};

console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("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"))
```

Answer (score 0):

well this is challenging but i figure it out

here is an O(n) solution. cant do better then this

```js
function lengthOfLongestSubstring(str) {
    var currentLength = 0;
    var result = 0;
    var keys = {};
    for (var i in str) {

        if (keys[str[i]] === true) {
            currentLength = 0;
            keys = {};
        }

        keys[str[i]] = true;
        currentLength++;
        if (currentLength > result) {
            result = currentLength;
        }

    }
    return result
}

console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("bbbbb"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("abcdaajkljl"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("pwwkew"));
console.log(lengthOfLongestSubstring("ysbghjjrfumqjpyktddsnxftvdqgxzlvrneaynufhgyqxwaqzelmbsiyxaubrqvguvehpmrykhvikkqzwttg"));
```

Comment: Yes, that seems to be working in the jsfiddle, it just fails on the leetcode site due to Time Limit Exceeded on a test with a very long string ```"ysbghjjrfumqjpyktddsnxftvdqgxzlvrneaynufhgyqxwaqzelmbsiyxaeubrqvguvehpmrykhvikokqzwttg"```. I really like your solution, but I guess it is not time efficient for them.

Comment: @ lilezek i mean in time efficiency not memory. you are right the arrays are not needed here . i will update the answer

Comment: But this doesn't solve `dvdf`, which the longest substring is `vdf` and is of length 3.

Answer (score -1):

Can use [`String#includes()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) to check if your substring has duplicates

```js
s = "anviaj"
s1 = "eeydgwdykpv"

function findLongest(str) {
  // reduce() iterates array created from split input and returns longest sub string
  return str.split('').reduce((a,c,i)=>{ 
    // start our substring using first character of str 
    let sub = str[0], j = 0; 
    // sub.includes(char) returns true if char already in sub string  
    while (++j < str.length && !sub.includes(str[j])) {
      // no duplicate so add char to substring
      sub += str[j];      
    }
    // remove first character from input string each iteration    
    str = str.slice(1);
    // replace current longest if applicable
    return  sub.length > a.length ? sub : a;
  },'');
}

console.log(findLongest(s))
console.log(findLongest(s1))
```

Comment: Well, it looks like a `O(n^3)` solution.